# How can I reset network (Airport) connections from the command line?

Tags: command-line, osx-snow-leopard, macbook

I have this MacBook Pro that has intermittent problems connecting to my WiFi network. Sometimes it helps to disable/re-enable Airport and sometimes I have to restart the computer to get my network running again.

Has anyone else experienced this? Are there any commands I can run that would do the same as I do when I restart the computer (short of actually restarting it, obviously) - or at least a command that restarts the Airport service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next time, try this from the command line:

```
sudo ifconfig en1 down
sudo ifconfig en1 up
```

This should bring your wireless interface down and then bring it back up.

Comment: en0 for me on an MBA.

Answer (score 9):

```
networksetup -setairportpower en1 off
networksetup -setairportpower en1 on
```

These are the commands I use to control Airport without the menubar icon. The advantage is that they don't require `su`/`sudo` privileges.

Comment: en0 for me on an MBA. But this command was smart enough to figure that out on its own.

Comment: I use my Macbook's en1 for Wifi sniffing using wireshark. Somehow I could not use the `airport --channel=` command to set a 5 GHz channel like 36 or 40, but all the 2.4 GHz channels worked. I had to earlier reboot my Macbook to fix this issue, but the `networksetup` commands seem to do the job much quicker :) BTW `ifconfig` `down` and `up` did not work in fixing this issue at least for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
d=$(networksetup -listallhardwareports | egrep 'AirPort|Wi-Fi' -A1 | grep -o en.)
[[ "$(networksetup -getairportpower $d)" == *On ]] && val=off || val=on
networksetup -setairportpower $d $val
```

The device name is `en0` on MacBook Airs. The port name was changed from AirPort to Wi-Fi in 10.7.